# How to determine when a process/data finishes loading?

Tags: python, user-interface, process, loading, pywinauto

I use pywinauto to manipulate a program on my computer

```
app = Application(backend="uia").start(r"cmd /c C:\Users\...\MyApp.exe", wait_for_idle=False)
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="MyApp.exe")
app['Dialog']['ComboBoxServices'].select(4)
app['Dialog']['Refresh'].click_input()
```

When I click that <kbd>Refresh</kbd> button, some date starts loading on the screen. It can take from 40 to 300 seconds. I would like python to identify when that data has finished loading. The data does not appear on another window so I can´t make python identify if another window appears. I need python to know when the data finishes loading.

Comment: an interesting feature is to check the load of the CPU 

_app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=5) # wait until CPU usage is lower than 5%_

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but it didn´t work. The program does not wait.

Comment: ok, sorry bout that, you could check further info on the specific documentation https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.application.html?highlight=wait_cpu_usage_lower#pywinauto.application.Application.wait_cpu_usage_lower

Comment: Hey, finally made "app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=5)" work. Thank you really much for the help. I really appreciate it.